# What is Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity  of this  algebra?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $M=\mathbb{C}[f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_r]$  is  finitely  generated algebra, $f_i \in S:=\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n],$   $\deg(x_i)=1, 1<\deg(f_i)<99.$  Suppose  that minimal free  resolution of $S$-module $M$ has  form 
$$
0 \longrightarrow  S(-102) \longrightarrow  S(-50) \oplus S(-20) \longrightarrow M \longrightarrow 0,
$$
Is it true  that the Castelnuovo-Mumford regularity of $M$  equals 100?

Comment: Well, the CM-regularity can be read off a resolution $\cdots \bigoplus S(-j)^{b_{1j}} \to \bigoplus S(-j)^{b_{0j}}\to M\to 0$ as $\max \{j-i : b_{ij}\neq 0\}$, so I guess you get 101.

Comment: Looks to me like M is a sub-algebra of S. How is the S-module structure defined on M ? 

Comment: Yes, I wondered about this too. Perhaps you should clarify the question, Melania..

Comment: Yes,  of cource $M$ is subalgebra of $S$.
@J.C. Ottem. I thought  that $M=S(-\deg(f_1)) \oplus S(-\deg(f_2)) \oplus \cdots \oplus S(-\deg(f_r)).$  Then the  ansver is 100.